# Error 87 When Using DeviceIoControl(FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS)

Tags: python, winapi, handle, createfile, deviceiocontrol

I'm trying to get the physical location of a file on the disk.
This is the current code:

```
import win32file
import winioctlcon

handle = win32file.CreateFile(raw_input("File: "), win32file.GENERIC_READ, win32file.FILE_SHARE_READ | win32file.FILE_SHARE_WRITE, None, win32file.OPEN_EXISTING, win32file.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | win32file.FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,None)
loc = win32file.DeviceIoControl(handle, winioctlcon.FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS,"",8192,None)
```

When I try to run the code, I get this error:

```
pywintypes.error: (87, 'DeviceIoControl', '\xfe\xfe\xe4\xf4\xf8\xee\xe8\xf8 \xf9
\xe2\xe5\xe9.')
```

This error is "Invalid Parameters". What parameters did I use wrong?

Comment: of course invalid parameter because you call `DeviceIoControl` absolute incorrect . less parameters than must be. where is `STARTING_VCN_INPUT_BUFFER` ? where is `RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER` ?

Comment: How do I get these parameters' values?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364572(v=vs.85).aspx) MSDN site.

Your count of parameters is incorrect. You need an input buffer and an output buffer. Input is the start VCN (>=0), handle need to be a alternate stream, file, volume or directory handle. Input buffer is of type

```
typedef struct {
  LARGE_INTEGER StartingVcn;
} STARTING_VCN_INPUT_BUFFER, *PSTARTING_VCN_INPUT_BUFFER;
```

Comment: really `StartingVcn >= 0` (not `>0` )  and file can not be *volume* handle. only alternate stream, file, or directory

Comment: You are correct VCN >= 0. Handle can be a volume handle see documentation "This parameter can optionally be a handle to an NTFS volume."